# Add a character to the beginning of each line only if it's not already there

Tags: sed, regular-expression

Given this example of a text file containing only some usernames separated by lines:

```
@Alice 
@Bob 
Cindy 
Leon 
@Mark
```

How can I add `@` to the beginning of every line that doesn't have it already?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Statements in `sed` scripts have a `[address[,address]][!] action` pattern, where `address` can be a line number or `/regexp/` and the address(es) can be reversed with `!` (not), so here you'd write:

```
sed '/^@/! s/^/@/' < file
```

To add a `@` to the start of lines that don't already have one.

The address is `/^@/` (lines with `@` following the start of the line (`^`)), `!` reverses it so that the `s/^/@/` action (`s`ubstitute the start of the line with `@`) is only run on the lines that don't match.

You can achieve the same effect with:

```
sed 's/^@\{0,1\}/@/' < file
```

Which replaces 0 or 1 `@` at the start with `@`. Same with EREs:

```
sed -E 's/^@?/@/' < file
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it a kind of "if" in the first command? Why separated by a space?

Comment: @SeppA see edit.

Comment: @Quasímodo, yes, though that wouldn't insert a `@` if the first bytes of the line could not be decoded into a character in the locale (like on the output of `printf '\311ric\n'` (the iso8859-1 encoding of Éric) if run in a locale that uses UTF-8 (in any case the behaviour of sed is unspecified on non-text input). That would also not add a `@` at the start of empty line (which may or may not be better).